# How are mutable and immutable class variables initialized?

Tags: python, class-variables

Running the sample code below:

```
class S:
    i = 0
    a = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.i += 1
        self.a.append(1)

s1 = S()
print((s1.i, s1.a))

s2 = S()
print((s2.i, s2.a))
```

The output will be:

```
(1, [1])
(1, [1, 1])
```

Why is `int` `S.i` reset to 0 for `s2` but the `list` `S.a` does not reset to empty? I think it has something to do with the immutable `int` vs mutable `list` but could someone help to express more details what happened to the two class variables during the two init calls?

Comment: `a` is a class attribute, shared by all instances.  `i` is an instance attribute.  Mutability doesn't really have anything to do with it, other than making it easier to change the value of `a` without making it an instance attribute as well.

Comment: @jasonharper can you clarify why `i` is an instance attribute? Both `i` and `a` are defined outside of the constructor.

Comment: `i` is initially a class attribute, but when you reassign it, it becomes an instance attribute.  The difference is that you never actually reassign `a`, you just mutate its existing value.

Comment: Ah I see it now as others have pointed it out too, thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.i += 1
```

is equivalent to

```
self.i = self.i + 1
```

When the instance variable does not exist, the value is looked up on the class, so in this scenario, it is equivalent to

```
self.i = S.i + 1
```

After you define `self.i`, then any further value lookup is on the instance variable, not on the class variable. So after this line, you have `S.i = 0` and `s1.i = 1`. Since `S.i` is not modified, `s2.i` also becomes `1`.

On the other hand,

```
self.a.append(1)
```

does not create a new instance variable, but appends an element to the existing class variable.

Comment: why the result is still same if I do `self.a += [1]`. What is the reason new instance variable is not created in this case?

Comment: @Avinash Because `self.a += [1]` is AFAIK equivalent to `self.a = self.a.__iadd__([1])` (see [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__)); but unlike `list.__add__` which produces a new list, `list.__iadd__` mutates the list and returns the same list. Notice that `self.a = self.a + [1]` will give you a different result than `self.a += [1]`. The instance variable _is_ created, but it refers to the same object as the class variable (`S.a is s1.a`), so if you affect `s1.a`, `S.a` and `s2.a` follow suit.

Answer (score 2):

So you are altering the instance attributes when you call `s1.i` or `s1.a`.  To change the class attributes try this:

```
S.i += 1
S.a.append(1)
```

In your constructor you initialise `self.a` and `self.i`.  this creates instance attributes that belong to each instance of the class.

The `a` and the `i` declared outside the constructor are class attributes and are shared by all instances.

The reason `s1.a` and `S.a` updates regardless of which attribute is used is because lists are mutable and both the instance and class variables are references to the same list.

Answer (score 2):

```
class S:
    i = 0
    a = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.i += 1
        self.a.append(1)
```

the list as defined by `a = []` is a class attribute.  It's instantiated when the class is defined, and remains the same list object.  Any instances of this class are going to reference the one list.

If you want to have an empty list for every new instance, then move the list definition to within the `__init__` method:

```
class S:
    i = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []
        self.i += 1
        self.a.append(1)
```

Result:

```
>>> s1 = S()
>>> print((s1.i, s1.a))
(1, [1])
>>> 
>>> s2 = S()
>>> print((s2.i, s2.a))
(1, [1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this particular code is written abstracts some of what Python is doing behind the scenes here, so let's go through it.

When you define the class, and you define variables outside of any function like you do at the beginning in your code, it creates *class attributes*. These are shared among *all* instances of your class (in your case, `s1` and `s2` are both sharing the same reference to your `i` object and your `a` object).

When you initialize the class, you are calling the `__init__` function, which, in your code, first calls `self.i += 1`, and I think this is where most of the confusion is coming from. In Python, integers are immutable, so they *cannot* be overridden. By calling `+=`, you are removing the reference to your old `i` variable and creating a new one referencing a different place in memory. But because you are now in a function in your class, it's being defined as an *instance attribute*. Instance attributes are *not* shared among different instances of your class.

However, lists *are* mutable. So when you append `1` to your list, you are *not* creating a new instance variable, so it keeps the same reference to the class attribute, and therefore when you initialize your class the second time, it adds it onto the class attribute that already has been populated once when you created the first instance.