# Why does pytest.fixture not create a new object for each test?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I want to test an object with a list property, so I created a python fixture for the OuT.
I expected it to create a new instance of the OuT for each new test. However, test2 below fails because of `1 != 0` implying foo.x is not empty.

How can I make sure pytest creates new instance for every test?

```py
import pytest


class Foo:
    x = []


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def foo():
    foo = Foo()
    return foo


def test_1(foo):
    foo.x.append(1)
    assert foo.x == [1]


def test_2(foo):
    assert len(foo.x) == 0
```

Comment: It is creating a new `Foo` instance (do `print(id(foo))`), but the list instance is part of the class, not of the instance.

Comment: It's not pytest, it's plain Python behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are mutable and immutable class variables initialized on \_\_init\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313517/how-are-mutable-and-immutable-class-variables-initialized-on-init) (Your code does not use an `__init__`, yes, but the explanation in those answers explains what happens when you use dot notation to access `x` (`.x`))